# UrlRewriteFilter ERROR

Tags: url-rewriting, servlet-filters

I'm using maven and I put urlrewrite.xml under source folder src/main/resources/. Configure web.xml like this:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>confPath</param-name> 
    <param-value>classpath:urlrewrite.xml</param-value>             
</init-param>


</filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

but get err:org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter ERROR: unable to find urlrewrite conf file at classpath:urlrewrite.xml. If I put it in the default loc:/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml. It works. But I want to conform to the maven specs and put all configurations under resources folder.

Could anyone kindly help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>confPath</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

and Put the urlrewrite.xml file inside 'WEB-INF'
[This article](http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/Installation%3aURLRewriteFilter/) has the setup instructions.

Comment: Can I put it in other place? So what's the use of confPath param?

Comment: I found this issue is fixed http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/issues/detail?id=28 According to them, first the filter tries to load it from servlet context. If it
could not find one, it tries to load it from the system's classloader.

Comment: I see. I try to fix this issue by implements my own UrlRewriteFilter, but it seems to have too much dependencies. So I give up. I'll have to use the context path instead. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest solution in the world but I was able to find a work-around. Note that my application is spring-based:

public class EnhancedUrlRewriteFilter extends UrlRewriteFilter {

```
private String confPath;

private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog (getClass ());

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    String confPathStr = filterConfig.getInitParameter("confPath");
    confPath = StringUtils.trim(confPathStr);
    super.init (filterConfig);
}

@Override
protected void loadUrlRewriter (FilterConfig aFilterConfig) throws ServletException {

    try {  
        configure (aFilterConfig.getServletContext ());
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException (e);
    }

}

private void configure (ServletContext context) throws IOException {

    ResourceLoader webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext (context);

    Resource resource = webApplicationContext.getResource (confPath);

    logger.debug ("Loaded urlrewrite.xml from " + resource.getFilename ());

    InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();

    URL confUrl = null;

    try {
        confUrl = context.getResource(confPath);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        logger.debug(e);
    }

    String confUrlStr = null;
    if (confUrl != null) {
        confUrlStr = confUrl.toString();
    }

    if (inputStream != null) {
        Conf conf = new Conf(context, inputStream, confPath, confUrlStr, false);
        checkConf(conf);
    }
}
```

}

and in my web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>EnhancedUrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>confPath</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:urlrewrite.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
        <param-value>WARN</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```